# How to point Amazon DNS service to a specific folder on EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, windows-server-2012

I feel very dumb already. I have searched for the answer for 2 hours without any success.

I have bought a domain through Amazon - Route 53. It has created 2 hosted zones for me `NS` and `SOA` type.

I am unable to figure out how to point a specific domain e.g. `example.com` to a specific folder on the EC2 server.

Do I need to create that `A` type hosted zone? If yes, do I just put IP address into `value` field of that zone? If yes, how then it knows which folder should it pick?

Is there any set up to be done on the actual server(I mean through remote desktop)? Do I need to setup a DNS there? I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Use use route 53 and create an 'A' record which points the domain to the server ip address (you had that part right).

Step 2: In the IIS Admin/Manager tool you 'bind' a particular dnsname to a specific website that you previously setup in IIS.

You need to do both steps.

Comment: I get you, I was very mislead when I couldn't find the IIS. Do you know if I need to install it separately or is there any other tool? Thanks

Comment: Your server may or may not alreay have IIS setup on it; but if its not there, you should just be able to RDP in an turn that feature on.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I just had to enable it. For anyone encountering same problem, you may "enable/install" IIS through Server manager->Manage->Next...->Search in list option IIS